# List View Permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, list-view

I was wondering if you could set permissions for a specific list view in SharePoint 2013? I have a list that I want to grant access for a read-only view but I can't seem how to do this for specific email addresses within our organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set permission on the list level easily from the list settings page. navigate to the that page and under permission, you will have to break the inheritance and grant these people (direct adding of each of these individuals a read only access). Once you do that, all the list views will inherit the permissions from the list

Answer (score 1):

In OOB SharePoint, any user with read access can navigate to any views and we don’t have any permission which can be applied on the list view.

Please refer the workaround for the same in below given link.

[How to set View level permission for a List/Library in SharePoint](http://www.netwoven.com/2016/01/how-to-set-view-level-permission-for-a-listlibrary-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Views cannot have security applied to them.  They can have audiences.  There is a difference in that you are not preventing access, but directing users to relevant information.  As a point of note, search results of the list will return all results.

Comment: So basically, what if this was a wiki page? Can I still add a permission....I'm new to SharePoint so I'm trying to get all the answers

Comment: As Ahmed said, you can break the permission inheritance on each item (wiki page) and set the permission on each.  But this is an administrative nightmare and I strongly advise against it unless necessary.  If you must, use SharePoint groups to control the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

views are pages.. you can break page permission and grant special permission to it.